# Couldn't find Transmission's web interface files!

Tags: raspbian

I am trying to enable remote access to Transmission on my RPi. This is the error msg when I type `192.168.1.99:9091`

> **404: Not Found**
>
> Couldn't find Transmission's web interface files!
>
> Users: to tell Transmission where to look, set the TRANSMISSION_WEB_HOME environment variable to the folder where the web interface's index.html is located.
>
> Package Builders: to set a custom default at compile time, #define PACKAGE_DATA_DIR in libtransmission/platform.c or tweak tr_getClutchDir () by hand.

I can't find any guides on how to fix this.

It worked at one point. I think it stopped working after trying to setup apache2, php, and owncloud.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit 1:

I have figured out that I am missing the following directories found in transmission-common. Proven [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/transmission-common/filelist).

/usr/share/transmission
/usr/share/transmission/web

I probably deleted them while trying to reinstall. However now when I reinstall the packages, it does not recreate these folders. How do I make it create all those folders?

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out. I had to run:

```
apt-get install --reinstall transmission
```